# Money from close relative to close a home loan

Tags: india, home-loan

I have 15 lakh home loan, which I am planning to close by asking my relative to transfer directly to  the home loan account.

Is there any problem of taxation due to transfer of bulk amount to the home loan account?

Comment: Warning to people from the US who might be reading this. The question is written in Indglish, not American or British English. The OP has a loan secured by a house (possibly his personal residence) and he will be getting some money (as a gift?) from an unspecified relative and using it to pay off the loan. He is asking if there are any tax issues if the relative pays off the loan directly rather than by giving the money to the OP to deposit in his account and then the OP will pay off the loan from the OP's own bank account.  (Gifts from close relatives are not taxable in India)

Comment: Totally beside the point, but I think lakh and crore are amazingly useful words, and try to drop them in normal English conversation as often as I can.

Comment: @RupertMorrish Issue is western norm is to base things on thousands. not hundreds. So people find them very unintuitive to work with

Comment: @Vality Not really, expressions like fifteen hundred are quite common.